# Json.NET to list of class as attribute

Tags: c#, json, rest

I build a rest service which output are json. I using Newtonsoft.Json.

This is my class.

```
public class DownloadPDA
{
    public List<FRUTE> lsRute { get; set; }
    public List<FCUSTMST> lsCustomer { get; set; }
    public List<FMASTER> lsMaster { get; set; }
    public List<FNOTEC> lsNotec { get; set; }
    public List<FINFO> lsInfo { get; set; }
    public List<FBRAND> lsBrand { get; set; }
    public List<FKPL> lsKpl { get; set; }
}
```

but when I test my rest service my result are:

```
{"downloadDataResult":"{"lsBrand":[{}],"lsCustomer":[{},{},{}],"lsInfo":[],"lsKpl":null,"lsMaster":[{},{},{},{},{}],"lsNotec":[],"lsRute":[{},{},{}]}"}
```

it not show the data in list. I know something is wrong. Can anybody help?

This one of my collection class

```
public class FRUTE
{
    private String norute;
    private String custno;
    private String flag;
    private String st_visit;
    private float amount;
    private int jmlvisit;

    public FRUTE() { }

    public void getData(DCTRTDTO dto) {
        this.norute = dto.NOROUT;
        this.custno = dto.NOCUST;
        this.flag = dto.FLAG;
        this.st_visit = "not yet";
        this.amount = 10;
        this.jmlvisit = 1;
    }

    public static List<FRUTE> getList(List<DCTRTDTO> lsRute)
    {
        List<FRUTE> ls = new List<FRUTE>();
        FRUTE info = new FRUTE();

        foreach (DCTRTDTO dto in lsRute)
        {
            info.getData(dto);
            ls.Add(info);
        }

        return ls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of at least one of the classes used in your collections: FRUTE, FCUTMST, etc?

Comment: I have added it. How can i show the data of FRUTE in json?
I have debug it and found it have data but in my rest service it just display **"lsRute":[{},{},{}]**

Comment: just to confirm, did you make sure the classes in question are serializable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FRUTE class doesn't have public properties that are required for Json serialization.
Encapsulate you private fields and all will work as expected.

```
public class FRUTE
{
    private String norute;
    private String custno;

    public string Norute
    {
        get { return norute; }
        set { norute = value; }
    }

    public string Custno
    {
        get { return custno; }
        set { custno = value; }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Has it solved your issue? If `yes`, you can mark answer as accepted; if `no`, we can thin on something else.